# Saving attachments from .msg files with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, win32com

I am trying to download some attachments for a number of `.msg` files that reside in a folder (not in outlook specifically).

```
import win32com.client
import os
path = 'C:\\Users\\my_messages\\'
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if '.msg' in f]
print files
for file in files:
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(os.path.join(path, file))
    att=msg.Attachments
    for i in att:
        i.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, i.FileName))
```

I keep getting this error, which leads me to believe the `win32com` library has issues. Any help is much appreciated.

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32com\\gen_py\\00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x9x6\\ItemEvents.py.temp'
```

The error is generated on this line:

```
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(os.path.join(path, file))
```

Comment: Have you considered any of the existing solutions such as https://github.com/mattgwwalker/msg-extractor  rather than writing your own? If nothing else, you at least can look at how they're doing it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using their example of `python ExtractMsg.py example.msg` but get the error: `can't open file 'ExtractMsg': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. if I run `import ExtractMsg`, I have no issues. Maybe I just need to dig through the library's code.

Comment: It worked fine for me with `Python 3.6.0` installed with `Anaconda`. How did you install the `win32com` library?

Comment: @Adonis I thought that one was a built in library? If I am remembering incorrectly I believe I installed it with pip install win32com

Comment: I guess it would probably be more like `pip install pypiwin32`. Could you create a `virtualenv`, retry the install with `pip`, and run your script again? Also which version of `python` are you using?

Comment: @Adonis I successfully got it working on another computer. Uninstalling and reinstalling pypiwin32 didn't work. What did end up working was coping the files and folders from `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com` on the working computer and replacing that folder on the non-working. Seems a little sketchy but it works. Thanks

Comment: Without more information I can only guess you had a library conflicting with this one.

Comment: Or that you have a missing or invalid Outlook installation on that system where it doesn't work.

Comment: @IrmendeJong The OP clearly mentions copying the site packages from the 2nd computer to the 1st computer solved his issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was an issue with the library Python was using, as demonstrated by:

- `pypiwin32` (and more specifically the call `outlook.OpenSharedItem`) works with Python2.7 on a fresh install
- The OP managed to have it working after copying the library folder (`site-packages\win32com`) from a working install to his original (faulty) install

More investigation would be needed to have a clearer answer, at least **copying a working version of the library win32com** to the problematic install provides a workaround for this issue.